# Incrementing a variable inside a looped INSERT in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

How can we be able to include the other column to loop the same as the looped month in this code?

What I'm trying to achieve is the range of `$datestart` and `$dateend` should loop the `[Data 3]` as well.

If `[Data 3]` is equal to **100**, and the range of `$datestart` and `$dateend` is **10**

**Data 3** column should increment from **100,101,102,103,104,105.. and so on up to 110**

```
DECLARE @MYTESTTABLE TABLE  
                     (
                          [Month] DATE, 
                          [Data 1] INT, 
                          [Data 2] INT, 
                          [Data 3] INT
                     );

WITH MYLOOP AS 
(
    SELECT CAST('$datestart' AS DATE) AS [date], '$datavalue' AS [Data 3]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, [date]), [Data 3] = [Data 3] + 1
    FROM MYLOOP
    WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, 1, [date]) <  CAST('$dateend' AS DATE)
)
INSERT INTO @MYTESTTABLE ([Month], [Data 1], [Data 2], [Data 3])
    SELECT 
        LEFT([date], 10) AS [Month], 100 AS [Data 1], 100 AS [Data 2], [Data 3]
    FROM 
        MYLOOP

SELECT * 
FROM @MYTESTTABLE
```

Suppose `$datavalue` is equal to 100, and it will loop along with the range of the loop from `$datestart` to `$dateend`.

Example

[image: desc]

The next column (Data 3) should be **100,101,102,103,104,... and so on**

How can we achieve this?

I tried doing it like this `[Data 3] = [Data 3] + 1` but I get this error:

> Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "Data 3" of recursive query "MYLOOP".

Comment: Please check the data type of $datavalue, it appears from the error message that it is not an int.

Comment: @NeerajAgarwal I tried changing ````, [Data 3] INT);```` to ````, [Data 3] VARCHAR);````, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: You are adding 1 to [Data 3] which you cannot do with varchar. Use a variable of type int in place of $datavalue and initialize it to 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message just happens to be the first error that SQL Server picks.  There is in fact a great deal wrong with your SQL that SQL Server is not reporting.

Firstly T-SQL uses @variablename to denote variables (not $variablename).  Secondly enclosing something in single quotes (') will cause SQL Server to treat it as a literal string.  If you enter the following in a Query window:

```
SELECT CAST('$datestart' as date)
```

you will get a conversion failed error.

In addition I strongly recommend that you strongly type your variables @datestart and @dateend so that you do not need to use casts.

As an example try the following:

```
DECLARE @datestart date = '2019-01-01'
DECLARE @dateend date = '2019-11-02'
DECLARE @datavalue int = 100

DECLARE @MYTESTTABLE TABLE ([Month] date, [Data 1] INT, [Data 2] INT, [Data 3] INT);


;WITH MYLOOP AS (
    SELECT @datestart AS [date], @datavalue as [Data 3]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, [date]), [Data 3]=[Data 3]+1
    FROM MYLOOP
    WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, 1, [date]) <  @dateend) 

INSERT INTO @MYTESTTABLE ([Month], [Data 1], [Data 2], [Data 3])
SELECT [date] AS [Month], 100 AS [Data 1], 100 AS [Data 2], [Data 3]
FROM MYLOOP;

SELECT * FROM @MYTESTTABLE
```

This will give you data from 2019-01-01 to 2019-11-01.  Note I set @dateend as 2019-11-02, because you are using < @dateend.  This ensures that you will also get the desired last date.  Otherwise you can use <=.

Comment: This solves it, I noticed that by removing the  **(' ')** from **100** it works. But this is cleaner. Thank you.